# method is undefined for the type

Tags: java

Ok to be more clear I have this:

```
private static ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote service;

private List<Agentinfo> agentsActive;
..........
..........
agentsActive = service.getAgentsActiveOrSuspended();
```

And in `ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote` (which is an interface) I have

```
public abstract List<Agentinfo> getAgentsActiveOrSuspended();
```

And in `ServiceFilteredAgents` (class that implements `ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote`) I have

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "jpa")
private EntityManager em;
.............
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Agentinfo> getAgentsActiveOrSuspended() {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Agentinfo a)").getResultList();
}
```

I still don't understand why it say that the method `getAgentsActiveOrSuspended()` is undefined for the type `ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote`.

Thanks you in advance and tell me if you want I post all the code in my class

Comment: We can see getAgentsActive returns List<Agentinfo> what is the type if agentsActive variable I believe that the variable is not declared correctly.

Comment: "I put this method in the class ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote but it don't recognize it." Why don't you show us how, exactly, you added the method (i.e. show code).

Comment: Also, "Remote" sounds like it might be generated code.  Do a clean recompile and see if your changes are still there.